# Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid when using ant-design Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I have a problem when using a certain ant-design component: Dropdown.

The source code is written in ES6, and compiles fine using Babel.
When loading the page, the following error is thrown, and the page is not rendered:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Dropdown`.
    in Dropdown (created by Dropdown)
    in Dropdown (created by DashboardTemplate)
    in div (created by Col)
    ...
```

I'm using the code as listed in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/corneyl/be1ffa722d44c0ea3ede8d3ae40d1207) which has perfectly worked, but since some packages are updated doesn't work. I cannot reproduce the working version with downgrading all packages, due to the fact that dependencies of dependencies still are updated to a newer version. I can also not reproduce the problem in a Codepen example.

[Dropdown](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/dropdown/dropdown.tsx) is a ant-design component and used as instructed in the ant-design documentation.

Any clue what can cause this error?

Webpack is used as bundler, and installed package versions are:

```
$ npm ls antd react react-router react-dom prop-types webpack
E:\dashboard
+-- antd@2.11.2
+-- laravel-elixir-webpack-official@1.0.10
| +-- webpack@2.1.0-beta.22
| `-- webpack-stream@3.2.0 (git://github.com/jeroennoten/webpack-stream.git#d78a3568e259f9cdbc64c60290639af6ef6d3baf)
|   `-- webpack@1.15.0
+-- prop-types@15.5.10
+-- react@15.6.1
+-- react-dom@15.6.1
+-- react-icons@2.2.5
| `-- react-icon-base@2.0.7
|   `-- prop-types@15.5.8
+-- react-router@3.0.5
`-- webpack@2.6.1
```

Thanks!